# website on IE doesn't look right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on this website [formationMTL](http://formationmtl.com/)

The website looks great on all browsers exept IE.

Here's a snapshot from IE

[image]

I am new to this and don't know how to even tackle this issue. Any suggestions?

Note: IE version: 7.0.6002.18005

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please post any relevant code? I.e. the code for the paragraph that's not working correctly.

Comment: if I had a dollar for every site that didn't work in ie...start here: http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/

Comment: When asking IE-related questions like this, **please specify the IE version(s) that you're testing**. Also specify the browser mode that IE is using.

Comment: I'm afraid that i don't have a solution; but i can confirm that it's the `clear: both` which is causing this behavior.

Comment: Looks just fine in IE11.

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary floats in your CSS. You might want to refactor your code if you want to avoid this kind of `float/clear` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to break it to you but, even though there are long, drawn-out solutions you could spend days testing and adding conditionals for in your code (and for you I mean, literally days non-stop), it would be much more logical to put this in your `<head>` and call it a day:

```
<!--[if IE lt 9]>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {
    vs: {
        i: 8,
        f: 5,
        o: 12,
        s: 5,
        n: 9
    }
};
$buoop.ol = window.onload;
window.onload = function () {
    try {
        if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();
    } catch (e) {}
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js");
    document.body.appendChild(e);
}
</script> 

<![endif]-->
```

### [Browser-Update.org (even Hawaii.gov uses it)](http://www.browser-update.org/)

Comment: Users don't care about updating their browsers, they only want it to work. Forcing an update down their throats will only make them look for what they actually want somewhere else. Besides, the problem the OP is having is quite simple to solve.

Comment: Only 9% of users are using IE. Which means even fewer are using IE7. Unless you have a good reason to support IE7 (Website targets businesses on XP running IE7, etc), I think this is an elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe 9% is a global average, though I'd love to see the source for that stat. This percentage still depends on your public. I work for a company that has 700.000+ visitors per day. IE use is over 50%. If we pushed a change like that we would go bankrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `reset.css` that can reset the default browser CSS Behaviours before you apply your CSS, maybe it solve your problem, the `reset.css` can be found here: http://www.cssreset.com

Comment: A reset stylesheet won't help if the underlying markup is broken/invalid or mismatched.

Comment: Yes, but i said "Try" because i do not have sure that it will works, maybe in the case of @Kam it works.

Comment: I have a bad notice for you @Kam, you are about to spend Hours and Hours doing a epic battle versus Internet Explorer, the most evil "bowser" of the world to find out what is the minimal details that are messing up your CSS :) good luck

Comment: That reset.css might have caused problems with your nav menu now. The "contact us" menu is appearing on the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a clearing element after the downncontent div

```
<div class="downcontent">...</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div>
```

When working with floating elements, it is important to use a clearing element afterwards to help the browser render the elements in the correct order and placement. IE is certainly guilty of doing this incorrectly.

Comment: You have a `clear:both` on the `<p class="welcomedesc">` element. Try getting rid of that. I tried it using the F12 dev tools for IE and it fixed the float issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the clearing. Do this:

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1; // For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout)
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="subcontain">
    [...]
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="downcontent"></div>
        <div class="searchcourse"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unrelated, but might help you in the future. Replace this:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

With this:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`
`<html>`

This will make your markup less likely to trigger `Quirk Mode` on `IE`.

Comment: Whenever you _must_ float elements around (which should be avoided) *and* want them to clear content below them, wrap them with a container having this `clearfix` class. The container can be nearly any HTML tag. Works every time. Your issue is a classical example for the application of this fix.

Comment: Hi, I just added the css code above in my stylesheet.css and I added the clearfix code, it didn't work

Comment: Did you apply it **and** clear `IE7`'s cache? Do make sure you clear `IE7`'s cache properly before you dismiss any answer given to you here... Or nothing will work for you.